# UFW warns about ports in /etc/services. Can that be disabled?

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

Whenever I do certain ufw commands, like ufw status, it outputs this before printing the data I was after:

```
WARN: Skipping 'mysql': also in /etc/services
WARN: Skipping 'ntp': also in /etc/services
WARN: Skipping 'tacacs': also in /etc/services
WARN: Skipping 'tftp': also in /etc/services
```

Is there any way to tell ufw not to report that warning?  I tried a number of google searches, but the results are not helpful.  I do not want to turn off all warnings, just that one.  There might be other warnings about my config that I do want to see.

Comment: [Show the configuration](https://serverfault.com/posts/1111002/edit) it is warning about. Sounds like you have configured services with names that are already in /etc/services.

Comment: What config specifically are you after?  There are a number of possibilities.

Comment: Here is the entire contents of /etc/ufw/user.rules:

https://paste.elyograg.org/view/29511724

Comment: And here is the output from ufw status verbose:

https://paste.elyograg.org/view/2d02d37e

Comment: Of course I used names that were already in /etc/services.  What else do you attach to a rule for port 3306 other than mysql?  I suppose I could have called it mariadb, but I'm not running that, I am running actual mysql.